# How to generate URL for a PNG file in repository

Tags: javascript, image, url, imageurl

I am using the Stable Diffusion API for image generation, one of whose parameters is an image I will have to pass in as an URL string.

For example, if I want to use the image of a monkey, I can use

```
url: 'https://media.npr.org/assets/img/2017/09/12/macaca_nigra_self-portrait-3e0070aa19a7fe36e802253048411a38f14a79f8-s1100-c50.jpg'
```

However, I plan on using some images (PNG format) that I have stored in my local repository instead. Is there a quick possible way, or library (preferably in JavaScript) that allows me to dynamically generate an URL for the image? Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "local repository"? Can you share the code you are currently using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, when hitting the img2img endpoint of the stable diffusion API, the `init_image` parameter in the request body takes the image URL. Initially, I thought using the `URL.createObjectURL()` method in JavaScript to generate a temporary blob URL for local files would be the quickest way.

So I wrote a `.html` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Stable Diffusion API Example</title>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="file" id="input-file">
  <button id="generate-button">Generate Image</button>
 
  <script>
    const inputFile = document.getElementById('input-file');
    const generateButton = document.getElementById('generate-button');

    inputFile.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
      const selectedFile = event.target.files[0];

      if (selectedFile) {
        const imageUrl = URL.createObjectURL(selectedFile);

        generateButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
        const apiParams = {
            "key": "my-api-key",
            "prompt": "Penguins swimming",
            "negative_prompt": null,
            "init_image": imageUrl,
            "width": "512",
            "height": "512",
            "samples": "1",
            "num_inference_steps": "30",
            "safety_checker": "no",
            "enhance_prompt": "yes",
            "guidance_scale": 7.5,
            "strength": 0.7,
            "seed": null,
            "webhook": null,
            "track_id": null
        };

          callStableDiffusionAPI(apiParams);
        });
      }
    });

    function callStableDiffusionAPI(params) {
      const apiEndpoint = 'https://stablediffusionapi.com/api/v3/img2img';
      const myHeaders = new Headers();
      myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");

      const requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: myHeaders,
        body: JSON.stringify(params),
        redirect: 'follow'
      };

      fetch(apiEndpoint, requestOptions)
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then(result => console.log(result))
        .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I uploaded an image and clicked on the Generate button, I got the following error in the console:
`{"status":"error","messege":"Invalid init_image URL"}`

However, when I stored a image URL from the internet in the `imageURL` variable and ran clicked on the Generate button, the API request was successful. Similarly, if I upload my local image to a cloud platform and use its public URL and store it in the `imageURL` variable, the API request is successful.

Thus, the Stable Diffusion API requires an image URL that's accessible from the internet, not a local blob URL. If you want to use a local image, the quickest way actually seems to be to upload it to a server or an image hosting service and use its internet-accessible URL. There are several platforms and services you can use to host images. Some common options for you would be: Imgur, Cloudinary, GitHub Pages, and Google Drive. Some of these options actually allows to do uploads programmatically which would be efficient in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

If uploading the images to the internet for the API to get access to them is not an option you can use data urls. Encode the file into a data url and use that in the request.